# Modify all file names in directory via CLI - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I am new to both Linux and the command line. I'm trying to rename all the files in a directory (anotherExampleDOM) such that they are simply appended with '_2'.

E.g. 'myFile.txt' would become 'myFile_2.txt'

The files do not all share the same extension. I have investigated the 'rename' command in conjuction with Perl's regular expressions but cannot find any examples of what I'm trying to acheive. I have also attempted to use a for loop as show below but received a bash syntax error near unexpected token 'do'.

```
$ for FILENAME in /home/tnargi/Documents/anotherExampleDOM/*; do mv $FILENAME $FILENAME_2; done
```

I'm sure this cannot be a difficult thing to acomplish but I'm not getting anywhere. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for FILENAME in  /home/tnargi/Documents/anotherExampleDOM/*; do mv $FILENAME `basename $FILENAME .txt`_2.txt; done
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for files that already have the '.txt' extension, for other files it adds '_2.txt' to the filename in addition to its prior extension.


i.e. exampleFile.xml is becoming exampleFile.xml_2.txt (instead of exampleFile_2.xml)